# "Correct" casting for g_signal_connect() using GTK?

Tags: c, gtk, glib

`g_signal_connect()` expects a `gpointer`, a character constant, a `GCallback`, and another `gpointer` as parameters.

I'm reading through the Foundations of GTK+ book right now and it just occurred to me that the author tends to cast the first parameter as a `G_OBJECT` and the last as a `(gpointer)`, even though both are defined as `gpointer`'s in the function signature and both parameters are `GtkWidget`s.

So, which (if either) is the most appropriate cast for this function? It seems strange to use two different casts.

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to use the `G_OBJECT()` cast macro for the first parameter: the GSignal API does not require GObject — it can be use with any GTypeInstance implementation.

you also don't need to cast to `gpointer` the last parameter, unless you're using a C++ compiler; `gpointer` is a typedef to `void *`, and the cast between pointer-sized types and `void *` is implicit in C.

Comment: To add to this: G_OBJECT() macro will do cast checking, producing a warning when a non GObject type is passed in.

Answer (score 1):

A minor point, but `g_signal_connect()` is actually a macro which calls `g_signal_connect_data()` -- not that it really makes any difference. The parameter types you've listed are correct, though.

In C, any pointer type can be implicitly converted to a `void*` (aka `gpointer`), so no explicit casts are required at all. Indeed, the whole reason that the first parameter has type `gpointer` rather than `GObject*` is to save you having to do a manual cast. I haven't seen the book, but it strikes me that the convention the author has settled upon is rather... unusual, to say the least. I don't think I've seen any GObject code "in the wild" where this is done.

As an aside, if you are connecting one `GObject` to another -- for example, if the recipient of a signal is a `GtkWidget` -- then it's better to use `g_signal_connect_object()` rather than a plain `g_signal_connect()`. If you do this, it will ensure that the signal is automatically disconnected when the receiving object is destroyed, which otherwise you would need to handle manually in the receiver's destructor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that `g_signal_connect_object` documentation says `there is a bug in GObject that makes this function much less useful than it might seem otherwise. Once gobject is disposed, the callback will no longer be called, but, the signal handler is not currently disconnected. If the instance is itself being freed at the same time than this doesn't matter, since the signal will automatically be removed, but if instance persists, then the signal handler will leak. You should not remove the signal yourself because in a future versions of GObject, the handler will automatically be disconnected.`

Comment: A quick google: https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=jcb6UrjLJIWq0QX65oGQDQ#q=G_OBJECT+g_signal_connect suggests that casting to G_OBJECT, while not necessary, is certainly a common idiom in 'the wild'

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: it is a remnant from the old Gtk+ 1 days when the function was `gtk_signal_connect` and it took a `GtkObject` as the first argument.